# Perguntas ruins e que provavelmente serão fechadas devem ser respondidas?

Tags: debate, respostas

Muitas vezes aparecem perguntas incompletas ou muito específicas, mas que possuem respostas e as vezes as respostas são bem simples e podem ajudar outras pessoas.

Tenho como hábito enviar uma edição para análise para tornar a pergunta mais genérica e englobar um número maior de cenários. Além disso, **tenho como hábito responder a pergunta**, quando possível mesmo sabendo que ela não está corretamente formulada e que pode ser fechada. E quase sempre as respostas nessas perguntas, mesmo que genéricas, exemplificadas e bem formuladas, são negativadas (mas a questão não é essa).

A questão é:

##### é recomendado ou não responder perguntas mal-formuladas (mas que como eu disse, possuem resposta), mesmo sabendo que elas podem ser fechadas posteriormente?

Comment: Teve mais debates sobre o tema, linkei os 1os que achei, mas podemos atualizar conforme o tempo. Ainda, já teve discussão que menciona negativar incentivo a práticas inadequadas ao objetivo do site, acredito que responder sabendo que é ruim se encaixa nisso. Lembrando que se for só pra ajudar, o campo de comentários (e mais algum pastebin da vida) geralmente resolvem. Quanto mais postagem que não cumpra o objetivo de repositório para público amplo, mais ruído atrapalhando quem pesquisa por um problema já respondido. O sistema tem um coletor de lixo, respostas atrapalham o algoritmo.

Comment: Eu usualmente faço assim (é uma questão bem pessoal, mas só como exemplo): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/559689/erro-ao-converter-uma-string-de-um-n%c3%bamero-decimal-em-float#comment992455_559689 - desta forma ajudo o caso específico, mas o GC do site limpa a postagem com o tempo. Tem uma menção no "[Que erro cometi ao formular minha pergunta?](/q/8388/70)" que é sobre responder "enunciados" também.

Comment: perfeito. Faz sentido e ficou muito claro pra mim agora.